# DataAnnotationsValidator and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I am running into a problem when using the [DataAnnotationsValidatorRecursive](https://github.com/reustmd/DataAnnotationsValidatorRecursive)

I have a class Information where the Product property is required. However, I have inherited the class and I want to change the property to NOT required.

```
[DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(InheritedPaperwork))]
    public class Paperwork
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public Information Information { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Information
    {
        [DataMember, Required]
        [JsonProperty]
        public Product product { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class InheritedPaperwork : Paperwork
    {
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class InheritedInformation : Information
    {
        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty]
        public new Product product { get; set; }
    }
```

However, when I deserialize a JSON object into a `InheritedPaperwork` object, the result I get is that a `Product` is required

```
var inheritedPaperwork =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InheritedPaperwork>(
        "{\"Id\": \"1\",\"Information\": {\"product\": null } }");

            List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            Assert.IsTrue(
                new DataAnnotationsValidator.DataAnnotationsValidator()
                    .TryValidateObjectRecursive(
                        inheritedInformation,
                        results),
                string.Join(
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    results));

Assert.IsTrue failed. The Product field is required.
```

How and is it possible for the Validator to "see" the derived class ?